# LSTM hyperparameters not available in model.summary() after loading model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, hyperparameters

I try to load a LSTM model (created by Keras) after using the command:

```
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

with the command:

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

and to print the lr and other hyper-parameters via the command :

```
loaded_model.summary()
```

I received all the information about the structure of the LSTM. But I did not receive the hyper-parameters information like the lr etc.

Comment: As @today's answer already implies, such parameters are not part of `model.summary()`, irrespectively of loading & saving the model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning rate is a parameter of the optimizer of the model and is not included in the `model.summary()` output. If you want to find the value of learning rate, you can use `optimizer` attribute of the model and use `K.eval()` to evaluate the learning rate tensor and get its actual value:

```
print(K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

**Update:** the optimizer of the model is not saved when you use `to_json` method and therefore the above solution does not work. If you want to save the whole model including the layers weights as well as the optimizer (along with its state), you can use `save` method:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Then you can load it using `load_model`:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Alternatively, if you have used `save_weights` method (to save the weights of layers) along with `to_json` method (to save **only** the architecture of the model), then you can load back the weights after loading back the model using `model_from_json`:

```
# load the architecture of model from json file ...

# load the weights
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

However, the optimizer in this second approach has not been saved and therefore you need to recompile the model (note that this means the state of the optimizer is lost and therefore you may not be able to easily to **continue training** the model without configuring the optimizer first; however, this is fine if you only want to use the model for **prediction** or **retrain the model from scratch**).

I highly recommend to read the related section in Keras FAQ as well: [How can I save a Keras model?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

Comment: I received error message 'sequential' object has no attribute 'optimizer' when I run the command print(eval(loaded_model.optimizer.lr))

Comment: @MAK Which version of Keras are you using, i.e. `print(keras.__version__)`?

Comment: I am using Keras version 2.1.6

Comment: @MAK Could you upgrade Keras and see if the error is resolved?

Comment: it's little problematic for me. because I am working with air gap computer (no internet connection)

Comment: @MAK Oh, wait a minute: you are saving the model using `to_json()` method? The optimizer of the model is not in the output of `to_json()`. Only architecture the model is saved.

Comment: OK that what I see when I look in the json file , the optimizer information is not saved..., So now I have two questions: 1. How to save model with all of his information? 2. If I already save the model by to_json command, how to update the model with all the information like optimizer , input shapes etc' ,after loading?

Comment: @MAK 1) Use `save` method: `model.save('my_model_name.h5')`.